# Accessing a web application running in Ubuntu from other machines in the same network

Tags: networking, server

I have an application running in Ubuntu 22 that deploys a web server at port 8000 and it's accessible through the browser at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ (from the same machine). I would like to access this URL from other machines in the network so I tried using the IP address http://192.168.1.21:8000 (rather than the localhost one; 127.0.0.1) and I checked the port 8000 is opened in the firewall... But so far, I can't access this website from outside the Ubuntu machine... I'm wondering if I need something else to configure in Ubuntu to make this work. In windows, you can access any webserver running at localhost using the machine's IP address (assuming the port is opened in the firewall), but it seems this is not the case in Ubuntu? Note that I don't have a webserver such as Apache installed and running, but the application itself deploys a webserver so I assume this is not needed.

Thanks in advance Gus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux operating system is similar to Windows in terms of network services. A running service and an open port on the firewall should be enough.

But beware. An application can **only** have a port open for **local access**. You will find this by making sure that the listening address of the network service is not 0.0.0.0, but only 127.0.0.1.

Use the `netstat` command and pay attention to the third column. The full command with parameters is below.

The following case shows two services, one of which listens only locally (TCP port 5939) and the other is accessible over the network from other addresses (TCP port 10000).

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939          0.0.0.0:*               LISTENING  2638/teamviewerd    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTENING  2797/perl
```

I assume your web server has an IP address 192.168.1.21.
Please attach here the system response to the following commands:

#### Server

```
sudo netstat -lntp

sudo iptables-save | grep -C 3 8000
```

#### Another PC in the same network (OS Linux)

```
ping -c 3 192.168.1.21

nc -4zv 192.168.1.21 8000
```

The netcat (`nc`) can be installed by:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install netcat-openbsd
```